# Cellular Boundary map coincides with Simplicial Boundary map in the case $n = 1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

In Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* on page 140,  he writes that it is easy to compute the *cellular boundary map* in the case $n=1$, since $$d_{1}:H_{1}(X^{1},X^{0}) \rightarrow H_{0}(X^{0})$$ is simply the same as the *simplicial boundary map* $$\Delta_{1}(X) \rightarrow \Delta_{0}(X).$$

Why exactly is this the case?

**Added by TheGeekGreek**: I would also like to address the question on the sense or interpretation of $\Delta_\ast(X)$, where $X$ is a cell complex, because not every cell complex is triangulable.